# Viewport performance due to high poly count

Tags: 3d-view, performance, polycount

Is there a way of reducing poly count only in the viewport?

My gtx 1070 is struggling while sculpting terrain (It has 2000x2000 subdivisions)

Comment: The [multiresolution modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/multiresolution.html) is probably what you are looking for, but you might also want to try [dynamic topology sculpting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/sculpt_paint/sculpting/adaptive.html).

Comment: @gandalf3 no, I have a 2000x2000 mesh that is already subdivided without modifiers. I'd like to reduce the poly count rendered in the viewport, because it's impossible to sculpt with so many polygon's due to lag